# Function prompts value for Add-Content and treats .txt file as directory

Tags: powershell, user-defined-functions, powershell-4.0

I am writing a PowerShell script for creating error status files. The info I need is defined in a global variable (`$info`) and is returning the correct string I need it to. The type is `System.String`.

```
function Add-Fail
{
    $date = Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd"
    Add-Content \\Path\To\FailMonitor\${date}.txt $info
}
```

I have also tried passing the variable like this:

```
function Add-Fail ($info)
{
    $date = Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd"
    Add-Content \\Path\To\FailMonitor\${date}.txt $info
}
```

and calling it like this where info is a string:

```
    Add-Fail($info)
```

and this

```
    Add-Fail -info $info
```

For both of these cases, I get the same output which is asking for a value. If I input values, it keeps prompting me for the next one in an infinite array. If I don't input one and just hit enter, it gives me an error that has no information, and even refers to my `Add-Content` line on the complete wrong line number.

Output (Edited out username):

```
cmdlet Add-Content at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Value[0]: 1
Value[1]: 2
Value[2]: 
Add-Content : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
At C:\Users\********\Documents\Workspace\Error_Monitor.ps1:40 char:5
+     Add-Content \\nserver\scsi\HPQ\FailMonitor\$date\
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (\\nserver\scsi\...tor\2016-10-18\:String) [Add-Content], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand
```

As you can see, it refers to my date as a directory. For reference, my `Add-Content` expression is on line 45, char 5. It sees my .txt file as a directory and treats it as such. The text file is not a directory at all. It isn't a variable problem either as I have cleared the variables. I have also tried no brackets around the date, but that didn't work either.

Why is PowerShell behaving like this? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried setting the full file path to a variable to pass to `ac`?

Comment: Restart PowerShell to have clean session and try again. Make sure that script file is saved.

Comment: Look like the function was initialized after the script.

Comment: So the issue is resolved?

Comment: The issue is resolved. Incorrect code detection is keeping me from editing the post with a solution explanation though.

Comment: That should be posted as an answer of your own. Don't edit a solution into your question.